# How to access Dictionary Generic object in javascript which passed from server side

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to access Dictionary Generic object(pass from asp.net server side) In javascript...
& i also want to  retrieve that dictionary as key ,value pair ..

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read up on the JSON format.

Comment: Can you at least show us the object you're trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC this can be easily achieved with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
  // go ahead and use the model javascript variable to bind with ko
</script>
```

You just have to pass the to a view that contains that bits of code

Answer (score 0):

Its bit easy, Try to use below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var perm =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Message));
</script>
```